# Disable auto layout for one window

Tags: cocoa

I have a Nib file with two windows in it. Is there a way to disable Auto Layout for only one of the windows? The "Use Auto Layout" box in the Nib's File Inspector changes the setting for both windows.

Or do I have to create two separate Nib files?

Thanks!

/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it looks like that setting is nib-wide so you'll need two nibs.